# Why am i getting this ember-font-awesome error?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, font-awesome

I upgraded the current Ember app from 3.20 to 3.26 and we are getting this error from ember-font-awesome.

```
Template Compiler Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler) in ember-font-awesome/components/fa-icon/template.hbs

loc$$1.sliceStartChars is not a function
```

Any quick ideas before I jump down a rabbit hole?

Comment: you realize that `ember-font-awesome` is not really maintained anymore, you probably want to switch to the official `@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome`

Comment: as a community can we refrain from starting sentences with "you realize" or "you do realize"? I heard this all the time in engineering school, and I continue to hear it on TV, and (to me), it sounds very insulting to a person's intelligence. (but yes, folks should be using fortawesome's library)